# How to select an image from the gallery and convert it to Base64?

Tags: android, image, base64, android-imageview

In my application i want select image from *gallery*, convert to *base64* and then set into `imageView`.

I write below codes and show me *base64* in `LogCat`, when set this into `imageView` not show me any image!

I copy *base64* code from `logCat` to this site for see my image.

But it shows me empty image!

Site for test base64 : https://www.base64decode.org/

**My fragment codes:**

```
public class DashBoardFragment extends BaseFragment {

    /*    @BindView(R.id.addPhoto)
        ImageView addPhoto;*/
    private Handler handler;
    private Context context;
    private View v;
    private PrefsUtils prefsUtils;
    private ImageView addPhoto;
    private LinearLayout noLoginFrag_btn;
    private TextView textView2, dash_winnerTxt, dash_allBidsTxt, dash_allBidsTxt2, dash_winnerTxt2, dash_notWinTxt, dash_bougthTxt;
    private File file;
    private Uri uri;
    private Intent CamIntent, GalIntent, CropIntent;
    public static final int RequestPermissionCode = 1;
    private DisplayMetrics displayMetrics;
    private int width, height;
    private String base64String, base64StringForSite;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        handler = new Handler();
        context = getActivity();
        prefsUtils = new PrefsUtils(context);
        if (prefsUtils.isExist(PrefsKeys.PHONE_NUMBER.name())) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, null);
            addPhoto = v.findViewById(R.id.addPhoto);
            textView2 = v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            dash_winnerTxt = v.findViewById(R.id.dash_winnerTxt);
            dash_allBidsTxt = v.findViewById(R.id.dash_allBidsTxt);
            dash_allBidsTxt2 = v.findViewById(R.id.dash_allBidsTxt2);
            dash_winnerTxt2 = v.findViewById(R.id.dash_winnerTxt2);
            dash_notWinTxt = v.findViewById(R.id.dash_notWinTxt);
            dash_bougthTxt = v.findViewById(R.id.dash_bougthTxt);

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        textView2.setText(Constants.profileResponse.getRes().getUser().getName());
                        dash_winnerTxt.setText(Constants.profileResponse.getRes().getWinner() + "");
                        dash_winnerTxt2.setText(Constants.profileResponse.getRes().getWinner() + "");
                        dash_allBidsTxt.setText(Constants.profileResponse.getRes().getRegistered() + "");
                        dash_allBidsTxt2.setText(Constants.profileResponse.getRes().getRegistered() + "");
                        dash_bougthTxt.setText(Constants.profileResponse.getRes().getBought() + "");
                        dash_notWinTxt.setText(Constants.profileResponse.getRes().getRegistered() - Constants.profileResponse.getRes().getWinner() + "");

                        Glide.with(context)
                                .load(Constants.SERVER + Constants.profileResponse.getRes().getUser().getAvatarFile())
                                .asBitmap()
                                .centerCrop()
                                .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(addPhoto) {
                                    @Override
                                    protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                                        RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
                                                RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(), resource);
                                        circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
                                        addPhoto.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
                                    }
                                });

                        addPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                getImageFromGallery();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }, 1000);

        } else {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_no_login_dash, null);
            noLoginFrag_btn = v.findViewById(R.id.noLoginFrag_btn);
            noLoginFrag_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(context, RegisterPhoneActivity.class));
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
            });
        }

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            imageCropFunction();
        } else if (requestCode == 2) {
            if (data != null) {
                uri = data.getData();
                imageCropFunction();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == 1) {

            if (data != null) {
                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap bitmap = bundle.getParcelable("data");
                base64String = Base64ConverterUtils.convert(bitmap);
                Log.e("Base64Image", base64String);

                Bitmap bitmap1 = Base64ConverterUtils.convert(base64String);
                addPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
            }
        }
    }

    private void imageCropFunction() {

        try {
            CropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");

            CropIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");

            CropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            CropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
            CropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
            CropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 3);
            CropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 3);
            CropIntent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);
            CropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

            startActivityForResult(CropIntent, 1);

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

        }
    }


    private void getImageFromGallery() {
        GalIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(GalIntent, " Select image from gallery "), 2);

    }
}
```

**My Converter class :**

```
public class Base64ConverterUtils {
    public static Bitmap convert(String base64Str) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(
                base64Str.substring(base64Str.indexOf(",") + 1),
                Base64.DEFAULT
        );

        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.length);
    }

    public static String convert(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);

        return Base64.encodeToString(outputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
}
```

How can i fix it? Please help me

Comment: is your base64 a byte array or converted to string?

Comment: @ApoorvSingh, i can convert to string and show me this string. but when this string into above site not show me image ! how to fix it? please help me